# Handling relational tables as entities with Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need some help dealing with a relational table that is an entity due to the existence of an additional property.

Here is a gist of the entities in question: https://gist.github.com/chasepeeler/efd7efd890c58eafb81f

Do I have something configured wrong that is forcing me to do the flush in controller.php line 15?

I've also tried just updating the rank attribute of the queueItem record in the Queue::queueItems collection, but when I do that, it doesn't even save the changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

`$queueItems->clear()` does the same thing as clearQueueItems, but one time.

And if you want to override current queue state, you should just implement and call `setQueueItems(ArrayCollection $queueItemList)` method.
UnitOfWork will compute your changes to insert and remove new/deleted items.

Every OneToMany annotated field should implement setItems, addItem and removeItem methods, where Item is related entity name.

Your sortQueue method shouldn't persist and commit changes into database.
It should only return a sorted Collection.

Maybe I didn't get that, it's hard to say what you want to achieve, controller's code says me nothing.